# Are there other types of labels that can be created other than the mailing labels?

Tags: address-labels

How do I create labels other than the mailing labels? I'd like to be able to simply print off name (and maybe position) labels. All I can find is the basic mailing label and I don't want to change the address settings, I still need that feature as well. Is it possible to create my own label? I am on wordpress. It would be great not to have to use another program. Whenever I try to remove tokens in the address settings, the pdf comes up blank....

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the same against wordpress and civicrm 4.7 demo

Their is an option called Name Badge - I guess that is what you are looking for

Go To Administer -> Communications -> Label Format

Then Add New Labal and give your setting - Sheet Size to envelope #9 (depends)

Once you have created Label format you should see that you have created an name Badge - Now Find contact - select about 50 records and in the actions you will see "Mailing Label - print"

In the next step select your Name badge format and print to PDF - you should get all the address as excepted else change setting

Also look for http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org i have created some Examples check before it gets refreshed

Refer to the link for more details 
https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/events/event-badges/

If you have any issues please let me know so i will post some screen shots - I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Name badge is connected to CiviEvent, so you need to have enables CiviEvent to use this